# Properly write into string in Matlab (efficient and preserving escape characters)

Tags: string, matlab

I have an abstract class `Writer` which allows clients to write into *something*. Could be the screen, could be a file. Now, I try to create a derived class to write into a *string*.

I have **two problems** with the denoted line in method `write(...)`:

1. It's probably very inefficient. Is there something like a string buffer in Matlab?
2. It writes escape sequences like `\n` plain into the string, instead of taking their actual meaning.

**How can I get the denoted line properly?**

Code:

```
classdef StringTextWriter < Writer

properties
    str;
end

methods

    function this = StringTextWriter()
        % Init the write-target which is a string in our case.
        % (Other Writer classes would maybe open a file.)
        this.str = '';
    end

    function write(this, val)
        % Write to writer target.
        % (Other Writer classes would maybe use fprinf here for file write.)

        % ?????????????????????????????
        this.str = [this.str val]; % How to do this properly?
        % ?????????????????????????????
    end

end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions point by point:

1. The closest notion to a string buffer would be a *string cell.* Instead of:

   ```
   str = '';
   str = [strbuf, 'abc\n'];
   str = [strbuf, 'def\n'];
   str = [strbuf, 'ghi\n'];
   %// and so on...
   ```

   one may use

   ```
   strbuf = {};
   strbuf{end+1} = 'abc\n';
   strbuf{end+1} = 'def\n';
   strbuf{end+1} = 'ghi\n';
   %// and so on...
   str = sprintf([strbuf{:}]); %// careful about percent signs and single quotes in string
   ```

   the drawback being that you have to reconstruct the string every time you ask for it. This can be alleviated by setting a `modified` flag every time you add strings to the end of `strbuf`, resetting it every time you concatenate the strings, and memoizing the result of concatenation in the last line (rebuild if `modified`, or last result if not).

   Further improvement can be achieved by choosing a better strategy for growing the `strbuf` cell array; probably this would be effective if you have a *lot* of `write` method calls.
2. The escape sequences are really linked to the `<?>printf` family and not to the string literals, so MATLAB in general doesn't care about them, but `sprintf` in particular might.